# Do chroma signals add any information to luma in YUV?

Tags: image, image-processing, camera, format, yuv

Consider the [YUV 422 picture format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) that I get from an image sensor. The luma (Y) carries 4 bits of grayscale information. Do the additional 2+2 bits of U+V add any additional info to the overall greyscale infrormation? In other words, if I convert a full YUV 422 color image back to greyscale, will it exactly equal the 4 bit luma (Y) information?

The question may probably also read like "does YUV 422 have 4 or 8 bits of grayscale information?".

Comment: Cross posted here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51164/do-chroma-signals-add-any-information-to-luma-in-yuv

Answer (score 1):

Y typically indicates luminance, and is the only component that contributes the the perceived brightness of a pixel. So yes, converting to greyscale is simply discarding the other two channels.

A great resource for everything color-related is [Poynton’s Color FAQ](https://poynton.ca/ColorFAQ.html).

From the FAQ, about “luma”:

> Many video engineers call it luma and give it the symbol Y'. It is often carelessly called luminance and given the symbol Y. You must be careful to determine whether a particular author assigns a linear or nonlinear interpretation to the term luminance and the symbol Y.

And regarding Y'UV:

> if someone hands you an image claiming it's Y' UV, chances are it's actually Y'CBCR, it's got the wrong scale factors, or it's linear-light.

Thus: be careful about what you actually have there!

Comment: Ok, so by "converting to greyscale is simply discarding the other two channels" are you saying that if I convert 8 bit color (say YUV422) to grayscale in post processing I will end up exactly with the Y luma 4 bit  initial information?

Comment: @Kozuch: I’m saying that you should, not that you will. What you will get depends on what you’re implementing, which I don’t have insight into.